# JAVA auto change value between two variables

Tags: java

I have two variables, I don't know how to automaticaly change value when each variable change value:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "ABC1DEF";    // first value is "1"
    int i = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(3, 4));
    System.out.println(i);
    // first question  
    a = "ABC2DEF";           // change value to "2"
    System.out.println(i);   // want value of "i" is "2" automaticaly?
    // second question
    i = 3;
    System.out.println(a);   // want value of "a" is "ABC3DEF" automaticaly?
}
```

see comment line and help me solution

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, auto means adding 1 to the generated value of i, in that case you can try writing

```
    int i = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(3, 4));
    System.out.println(i);
    // first question  
    a = "ABC"+(i+1)+"DEF";        // change value to "2"
    System.out.println(i);   // want value of "i" is "2" automaticaly?
```

Now if you do again

```
 int i = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(3, 4));
```

You'll get the value `i` as 2. And you can write the same line `"ABC"+(i+1)+"DEF";` to get the value `"ABC3DEF";`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a good place to customize your data and apply observer pattern(kind of at least).

```
class MyString {
    String representation = "ABC%dDEF\n";
    int i =1;
    void updateMyString(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    void print() {
        System.out.printf(representation, i);
    }
}

class MyNumber {
    int i = 1;
    MyString myString;
    void bondMyNumberWithMyString(MyString myString) {
        this.myString = myString;
    }

    void setNewValue(int i) {
        this.i = i;
        myString.updateMyString(i);
    }
}
```

It's just a draft but that's how I'd try to resolve your problem and maybe will give you some idea on how to proceed.

And how would that be used?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   MyString ms = new MyString();
   MyNumber mn = new MyNumber();

   mn.bondMyNumberWithMyString(ms);

  ms.print();

   mn.setNewValue(2);
   ms.print();

   mn.setNewValue(3);
   ms.print();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use a class

```
class Auto {
    int i;

    public void a(String a) {
        i = Integer.parseInt(a.substring(3, 4));
    }

    public void i(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }

    public int i() {
        return i;
    }

    public String a() {
        return "ABC" + i + "DEF";
    }
}

Auto auto = new Auto();     
auto.a("ABC1DEF");    // first value is "1"
System.out.println(auto.i());

auto.a("ABC2DEF");
System.out.println(auto.i());   // want value of "i" is "2" automaticaly?
// second question
auto.i(3);
System.out.println(auto.a());   // want value of "a" is "ABC3DEF" automaticaly?
```